# Fifteen puzzle, BFS vs DFS difference

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, sliding-tile-puzzle

I would like to double-check my answer to a question from a textbook, as I'm still new to the concept of the Depth-first search and the Breadth-first search. The question regards the Fifteen puzzle and goes as follows:

"For the given starting order show the first ten nodes to be generated by:
a) a depth-first search
b) a breadth-first search

The "starting order" can be seen in the picture below.

I was wondering if I'm correct in thinking that the following sequences of numbers would represent the steps taken by each search. Each number is a tile that's moved. i.e. the node that's being generated.

a) depth-first search: 12, 14, 8, 3, 9, 10, 5, 1, 7, 6

b) [edit] my BFS is in the comment below.

I do understand, of course, that there are many possibilities with each one, but I just wish to know if my two examples are correct.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

[image]

Comment: Your BFS is weird, what are you searching?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I've messed it up. Let me try again. I start by putting 3 nodes in the queue. '4 down', '8 right', and '12 up'. I explore '4 down'. The next 2 nodes that I put in the queue are '2 right' and '6 down'. Since '8 right' is second in the queue, I now explore the nodes connected to it, which are '2 down', '3 right' and '14 up', and I add them to the queue. At this point '12 up' is third in the queue. I continue by exploring the node connected to it, which is '14 right'. And so on...would that be correct?

Comment: Yes that would be correct.

Comment: @Ecto Thank you :] Does the DFS look ok too? I was basically exploring just one of the connected nodes, so 12, 14, 8, 3, 9, 10, 5, 1, 7, 6 would be my stack I assume.

Comment: Probably yes, I would say DFS is really not suitable for this problem as the "decision tree" may have infinite height

Comment: @Ecto Yes, my textbook did mention that but they just want to see that I understand the general concept. Thank you once more :]

Comment: Please [edit] to add all essential information to the post to make it useful.